# Suppose that $f$ has a minimal polynomial and is invertible. Then $f^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Suppose that $E$ is a linear vector space **of infinite dimension** over a field $\mathbb F$ and that $f$ has a minimal polynomial $\mu_f$.

Suppose also that $f$ is invertible. How to prove that $f^{-1}$ can be written as a polynomial of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $\mu(x)=a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$, then $f \circ (a_n f^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 \, id)=-a_0\, id$.